# Use map to access next element in array

Tags: swift, map-function

I want to transform an array of points into an array of lines like so:

```
let lines = points.map { $1 - $0 }
```

I get the error

```
Contextual closure type '(Point) -> _' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body
```

I understand why I am getting this, but I could have sworn I'd seen sample code on SO using multiple arguments in a map closure. Is there a similar function I'm not finding that can do this?

Comment: What is the expected result for a given array of points? A concrete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### My interpretation

Given an array of some `CGPoint(s)`

```
// pseudocode 
points = [a, b, c]
```

your want as output a list of segments

```
// pseudocode
segments = [(a, b), (b, c)]
```

### Implementation

```
struct Segment {
    let from: CGPoint
    let to: CGPoint
}

let points = [CGPointZero, CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2)]

let segments = zip(points, points.dropFirst()).map(Segment.init)
```

*@Martin R: Thank your for the suggestion!*

### Result

> [Segment(from: (0.0, 0.0), to: (1.0, 1.0)), Segment(from: (1.0, 1.0), to: (2.0, 2.0))]

Comment: Simpler: `zip(points, points.dropFirst()).map { Segment(from: $0, to: $1) }`

Comment: @MartinR: absolutely better than mine. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @MartinR: even simpler: `zip(points, points.dropFirst()).map(Segment.init)`

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is using reduce. lets have

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let n = 3 // number of points in the line
let l = arr.reduce([[]]) { (s, p) -> [[Int]] in
    var s = s
    if let l = s.last where l.count < n {
        var l = l
        l.append(p)
        s[s.endIndex - 1] = l
    } else {
        s.append([p])
    }
    return s
}
print(l) // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

the advantage is that number of points in the line could be defined